How do I prevent my app from going to the home screen after changing the icon programmatically?
I am trying to modify the app icon in Android programmatically was going through this link here.
This works properly and modifies the App Icon but when it modifies it goes back to the home screen. Can we modify the app icon without going back to home screen automatically?
Edit:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        val linearlayout : LinearLayout
        val button         : Button

        linearlayout = LinearLayout(this)
        linearlayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        button = Button(this)

        button.text = "Modify App Icon"
        button.setOnClickListener {

            NewIcon ()
        }

        val button1 = Button(this)
        button1.text = "Revert App Icon"
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            changeicon()
        }

        linearlayout.addView(button1)

        linearlayout.addView(button)


        setContentView(linearlayout)

    }

    private fun NewIcon()
    {

        val manager = packageManager

        // Enable new icon first
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName(this@MainActivity, "com.example.appicons.MainActivityAlias"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)

        // Disable old icon
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName(this@MainActivity, "com.example.appicons.MainActivity"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Enable New Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

    private fun changeicon() 
    {
        val manager = packageManager
        // enable old icon
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName(this@MainActivity, "com.example.appicons.MainActivity"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
        
        // disable new icon
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName(this@MainActivity, "com.example.appicons.MainActivityAlias"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Enable Old Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        Log.d ("TAG", "Inside onStop")
    }
}

If we see the above code, I am not sure at which line is my app causing the app to background.
If I see any food delivery apps like Zomato where if you have any Membership / license, so based on that it asks if you want to change the app icon? There it didn't went to the background after the app icon changes and hence want a similar experience.

Please edit a [mre] directly into your question so the question can stand on its own without relying on the external link and can therefore be more useful for future searchers.

@Marsroverr Added a reproducible example

Can somebody help here??
